# How to protect a pumpkin plant on the balcony?

Tags: pumpkins

I have planted a relatively large pumpkin plant without much hassle in a pot and now it's becoming relatively large and I have moved it to my balcony in a larger pot (approximately 60L).

Unfortunately, our winters here in Germany can become quite cold, especially now our climate has become a bit more extreme. I was thinking of caring for the plant in my house and then when winter is over put it back onto my balcony. This way I hope to protect it from the frost.

However, I have only seen people growing pumpkin plants for the pumpkins, not really for maintaining the plant. Can I maintain the plant "beyond" one harvest or will it just die after one winter regardless of the protection?

I find it hard to imagine that the plant regrows to cover an extremely large area every year, however maybe that's due to my inexperience.

Comment: Are you familiar with the terms “annual” and “perennial” for plants?

Comment: No, unfortunately I'm not.

Comment: I guess I have to say goodbye to my pumpkin plant.